# Why could fetching resources over the network require multiple roundtrips between the client and server?

Tags: optimization, rendering, browser-cache

I was reading at https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching the following information:

> Fetching resources over the network is both slow and expensive: the download may require multiple roundtrips between the client and server, which delays processing and may block rendering of page content, and also incurs data costs for the visitor.

Why could this `require multiple roundtrips`? Why not `a single roundtrip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a few bytes can be done in a single roundtrip. However, as stated by Ilya Grigorik at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#defining-optimal-cache-control-policy, "large responses require many roundtrips between the client and server".